# How to extract a single line in a TXT file

Tags: python, extract

**I already have a code that extracts the subject line of a letter from a txt file:**

```
import os
ans = []

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("subject"):
            ans.append(line)
        elif line.startswith("Subject"):
           ans.append(line)
    
with open('extracted_data.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in ans:
        wf.write(line)
```

**However, it gets formatted like this:**

```
subject: Block 8 of EricssonSubject: Block 9 of Ericssonsubject: Block 10 of Ericssonsubject: Block 11 of Ericsson
```

**When I want it to look like this:**

```
subject: Block 8 of Ericsson
Subject: Block 9 of Ericsson
subject: Block 10 of Ericsson
subject: Block 11 of Ericsson
```

How do I get it to format in the above desired way?

Comment: `wf.write(line + '\n')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
with open('extracted_data.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in ans:
        wf.write(line)
```

to

```
with open('extracted_data.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in ans:
        wf.write(line+'\n')
```